# MS Access 2010 Filter re-usable subform, based on parent field

Tags: mysql, forms, ms-access, filter, parent

Parent form has a textbox containing an ID

Subform (child form) is a multiform containing the ID's of things linked to the parent ID (and others)

Many *different* parent forms use the same subform (child form), which means the usual method of:

```
WHERE [Child_IDs]=[Forms]![ParentFormName]![ID_TextBox]
```

doesn't work directly, as once saved it overwrites the filters for the other parent forms (breaking them).

Whilst searching for a solution, everybody has been saying to use:

```
Me.Parent![ID_TextBox]
```

or

```
Parent![ID_TextBox]
```

to resolve the problem, yet when I try using them in the expression builder, it fails to find either `Me` or `Parent`. Aka does not work.

I'm also trying to keep this setup flexible enough to deal with multiple instances of the parent forms as well.

Am I going down the right track? Any suggestions on what I should do?

---

***DETAILED VERSION OF WHAT I'M DOING***

I'm trying to create a small requirements database to help me with a few projects I'm working on.

The record specific (parent) info is fine, as are most of the relationships as they're specific enough to directly link via `Link Master/Child Fields`.

The problem children are "Comments", "References" and "Tags", which link to EVERY type of record (even themselves, for simplicities sake).

I've created a query which unions all of the ID's of each table together, whilst putting them into a "standard" format `LLL000000`, where LLL is a three letter acronym (TLA) for the table.

Even if I separated the `LLL` out from the records, I'm *still* stuck because that TLA isn't referenced in the bounded parent form. If I could reference the parent directly and ask for its ID_TextBox field, I'd be fine. If I didn't have to reuse the same subform for multiple parent forms, I'd be fine.

Multiple form instances crop up with the "grandparent" form, which will (hopefully) view (at most) 2 of the parent forms simultaneously, including 2 of the same type.

I'm deliberately leaving the multiple instances till last as that's a headache I'd like to leave when the incentive equals instant completion afterwards (I've not been having fun with VBA either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a new field to all of the "main" tables which redundantly adds the three letter acronym to each record by default.

Since it's there I can reference it in the Master/Child Links section along with the ID (effectively reconstructing the LLL000000 ID, but needing to add more hard-coded values into the system and waste memory space...)

This is ***not*** an ideal solution as it just increases the maintenance overhead. (Not as much as some of the other solutions I thought of, but still).

As such, I won't mark this as *the* answer and instead, wait for other suggestions.